# Xcode6 GM "Code Sign error"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios-provisioning

When I use Xcode6 beta6 or Xcode5 to compiler my project on iPhone, everything works fine. But I updated Xcode to Xcode6 GM, something wrong happened and it shows :

"Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: applicationGroups.."

It means I have to update my certificate and provisioning profile to use those features?

Answer (score 0):

This may help to solve the problem http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found/